# In LoopbackJS: How to get server protocol (http or https) in a boot script or server side code?

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs

In a server side js file, say `send-email.js`, I am trying to create a hyperlink to send in an email

```
var config = require('../../server/config.json');    

function sendEmail() {    
    var url = config.protocol + '://' + config.host + ':' + config.port + '/login';
    //code to send e-mail follows...
}
```

I have protocol, host, and port configured in `config.json` file and using that I am able to create hyperlink successfully.

I am also using [boot scripts](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+boot+scripts) of LoopbackJS, where `app` parameter is passed as shown in the below code:

```
module.exports = function (app, cb) {
    var url = 'http://' + app.get('host') + ':' + app.get('port') + '/login';
}
```

I can get host and port but not protocol.

Now there are two ways to get host and port:

1. Using `config.json` file
2. Using `app.get` methods

There is no `app.get('protocol')` to get protocol so I configured it in `config.json` file but I would like to get protocol automatically to prevent changing file when deploying to a server.

Is there anything like getting protocol (or host and address too) automatically depending upon where this nodejs app is hosted instead of configuring it.

I am open to receive answers from NodeJS, ExpressJS, or LoopbackJS angles.

Comment: Can you use the *network path reference* instead? `'//' + app.get('host') + ':' + app.get('port') + '/login';` (note that the protocol isn't declared).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your main goal is to avoid changing the config file when deployed, there is another option.

Instead of getting the protocol in code, set up an environment variable on each host that will run the app. Then in config.local.js override the 'protocol' setting in config.json.

config.json:

```
{
  "restApiRoot": "/api",
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "port": 3000,
  "protocol": "http"
  ...
}
```

config.local.js:

```
module.exports = {
  "host": process.env.APPNAME_API_HOST,
  "port": process.env.APPNAME_API_PORT,
  "protocol": process.env.APPNAME_API_PROTOCOL
  ...
}
```

server boot config.sh or .bashrc (if bash) for the user running the app:

```
export APPNAME_API_HOST=0.0.0.0
export APPNAME_API_PORT=3333
export APPNAME_API_PROTOCOL=https
```

(If you are running with strong-pm, these would be set with the `slc ctl servicename env-set ENV=value` command.)

This allows you to use the same config.local.js file on any environment where the variables are set, and the environment configuration is host specific. No need to change the file, and the server env config can be automated and checked in as well.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I didn't know about environment specific configuration files which is also explained in the [loopback's documentation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/config.json). I am doing deployment for the first time so didn't know to search like this.